# How to fix this Spring MVC startup exception in tomcat?

Tags: spring, tomcat

Could somebody help me with this error regarding starting Tomcat + spring ?

I already clean everything, and when I go to localhost:8080/springmvc/hello_world.html I got a 404 page error.

Thank you so much guys.

```
02/06/2012 00:09:59 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Arquivos de programas\Java\jre6\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Arquivos de programas/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Arquivos de programas/Java/jre6/bin;C:/Arquivos de programas/Java/jre6/lib/i386;C:\Ruby193\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Arquivos de programas\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin;C:\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin;C:\spring-roo-1.1.3.RELEASE\bin;C:\Arquivos de programas\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Arquivos de programas\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\eclipse;;.
02/06/2012 00:09:59 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
AVISO: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SpringMVC' did not find a matching property.
02/06/2012 00:10:00 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
02/06/2012 00:10:00 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
02/06/2012 00:10:00 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 791 ms
02/06/2012 00:10:00 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
02/06/2012 00:10:00 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
02/06/2012 00:10:00 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
02/06/2012 00:10:00 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
02/06/2012 00:10:00 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 525 ms
```

Comment: Does the request log show you anything?

Comment: Is your project added to this server? i.e. if you select the server, right click and choose "Add and Remove", is your project in the "configured" section?

Answer (score 0):

if you found page 404, then it might the `hello_world.htm` page not found. 
The easiest way to start is to put in the startup page as `index.html` so page can be loded in from contex root.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your log output your application is not deploying. Are you sure you added your project to your server? I'm assuming you are using Eclipse. Right click on your Server and select Add / Remove. Your application should be under the configured.

[image]