# Error starting TOMCAT

Tags: java, tomcat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix this Spring MVC startup exception in tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859516/how-to-fix-this-spring-mvc-startup-exception-in-tomcat)

Someone knows what is happening ?

[image]

What is happening, do you guys know ? Where can I see the logs for more details ?

Here is what the console says:

```
02/06/2012 01:08:50 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Arquivos de programas\Java\jre6\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Arquivos de programas/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Arquivos de programas/Java/jre6/bin;C:/Arquivos de programas/Java/jre6/lib/i386;C:\Ruby193\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Arquivos de programas\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin;C:\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin;C:\spring-roo-1.1.3.RELEASE\bin;C:\Arquivos de programas\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Arquivos de programas\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\eclipse;;.
02/06/2012 01:08:51 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
AVISO: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:springapp' did not find a matching property.
02/06/2012 01:08:51 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
02/06/2012 01:08:51 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
02/06/2012 01:08:51 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 766 ms
02/06/2012 01:08:51 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
02/06/2012 01:08:51 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
02/06/2012 01:08:51 org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [109] milliseconds.
02/06/2012 01:08:51 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
02/06/2012 01:08:51 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
02/06/2012 01:08:51 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 522 ms
```

Comment: Looks like a success to me.  I see no errors.  Shall I call my optometrist?

Comment: Server has been started in 522 ms, What is problem you are facing? do you want us to explain server start-up life cycle? :)

Comment: Look in the manual. It will tell you where the logs are.

Answer (score 1):

(I was hoping that you might say *why* you thought there was an error here, but you haven't bothered. So ...)

There is no error in that log, and it looks like Tomcat has started up successfully and is running normally.  The only thing that appears slightly odd is that there are no startup messages from any webapps.  Perhaps you simply haven't deployed them yet ... or you've deployed them in the wrong directory.

The INFO message about the missing APR native code is harmless.  Tomcat works fine without it ... assuming that you haven't explicitly configured an APR connector in the `server.xml` file.

The AVISO message (strange category name ...) looks like it is telling you that you've made a mistake in the name of an attribute in some config file.  Maybe, the `"source"` attribute whose value you've set to `"org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:springapp"` has the wrong name?  Or it is on the wrong XML element?  If the problem is in your webapp's `web.xml`, it might be causing your webapp to not find any servlets to start ... or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat server log usually can be found here `${catalina.home}/logs/catalina.out` or `${catalina.home}/logs/tomcat.log`